# identifier "intrinsic function" is undefined

Tags: c++, intel, avx

when I compiled my intel AVX code using intrinsic functions and intel compiler 2016 in visual studio C++ 2015 that error appears for all intrinsics:
for example: **identifier"_mm256_broadcast_ss" is undefined.**

this sample of my code:

```
 a1=_mm256_set1_ps(a);
   for (i = 0; i<j1; i += 8) { 
    b1 = _mm256_load_ps(&b[i]); 
    c1 = _mm256_load_ps(&c[i]); 
    b1 = _mm256_mul_ps(b1, a1); 
    c1 = _mm256_add_ps(b1, c1); 
    _mm256_store_ps(&c[i], c1);
     }
```

can any one help me to avoid this error especially this error does not appear when I use the same compiler in inline assembly code?

thanks

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Did you `#include "avxintrin_emu.h"` as [specified here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-avx-cc-intrinsics-emulation)? Or similar?

Comment: I used #include<immintrin.h>,#include<intrin.h> , and my computer is i7 core.when I use  #include "avxintrin_emu.h" the compiler give that error " can not open source file  #include "avxintrin_emu.h"

Comment: Please [edit] your original question to include your code sample.  You want to provide an [mcve] from the outset in order to more easily answer questions that require some insight into your actual problem.